# What is a ctools plugin?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

What is a ctools plugin? Why would one want to use a ctools plugin ? What advantages does it have over the current hook system?

Is there currently documentation regarding usage of ctools plugin?

I often see contrib modules require ctools and depend on it. You see it in various different modules like commerce, feeds, etc.